# Difference between Uri.Builder appendQueryParameter() and query() when using query geo URI?

Tags: android, google-maps, uri, uribuilder

For the following code, why does `appendQueryParameter` open the correct given location but `query` does not?:

```
String address = "Mountain View, California, United States";
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("geo")
        .path("0,0")
        // here appendQueryParameter launches external Google Maps app with correct location but 
        // query(address) has the wrong location (user's current location), why?
        .appendQueryParameter("q", address);
Uri uri = builder.build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Android documentation for [appendQueryParameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder#appendQueryParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> Encodes the key and value and then appends the parameter to the query
>   string.

Whilst documentation for [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder#query(java.lang.String)) says:

> Encodes and sets the query.

Could the problem with `query` be due to the tag it uses? What tag would it be using?